# Laravel 5.2 cannot update record

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

I cannot seem to update my record.

My controller

```
public function add()
{
    return view('cars.add');
}

public function edit($id)
{
    $car = Cars::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
    return view('cars.edit', compact('car'));
}

public function store(CarFormRequest $request)
{
    $car = new Cars(array(
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'color_id' => $request->get('color')
    ));

    $car->save();
    $car->position_id = $car->id;
    $car->save();

    session()->flash('status', 'Successfully Added a Car!');
    return view('cars.add');
}

public function update($id, CarFormRequest $request)
{
    $car = car::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
    $car->name = $request->get('name');
    $car->color_id = $request->get('color');
    if($request->get('status') != null) {
        $car->status = 0;
    } else {
        $car->status = 1;
    }
    $car->save();
    return redirect(action('CarController@edit', $car->id))->with('status', 'The ticket '.$id.' has been updated!');

}
```

my routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'PagesController@home');
Route::get('/about', 'PagesController@about');
Route::get('/contact', 'PagesController@contact');
Route::get('/cars', 'CarsController@index');
Route::get('/cars/edit/{id?}', 'CarsController@edit');
Route::post('/cars/edit/{id?}', 'CarsController@update');
Route::get('/cars/add', 'CarsController@add');
Route::post('/cars/add', 'CarsController@store');
```

here is my view:

```
<div class="container col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<div class="well well bs-component">
    <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{!! csrf_token() !!}">
        <input type="text" id="color_id" name="color_id" value="{!! $car->color_id !!}">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Edit Car Information</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Car Name</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <input type="text" value="{{ $car->name }}" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Car Name">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="title" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Car Color</label>
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <label id="opt1" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" id="option1" autocomplete="off"> Red
                        </label>
                        <label id="opt2" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Blue
                        </label>
                        <label id="opt3"  class="btn btn-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Yellow
                        </label>
                        <label id="opt4" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" id="option4" autocomplete="off"> Green
                        </label>
                        <label id="opt5" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" id="option5" autocomplete="off"> Black
                        </label>
                        <label id="opt6" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <input type="radio" name="color" id="option6" autocomplete="off"> White
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
                    <button class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `{id?}` instead of `{id}` in your routes?

Comment: can you share your blade/html form structure?

Comment: i saw that in a tutorials thats what they use in it, are there any difference?

Comment: What are you getting when you `dd($car)` ?

Comment: @JilsonThomas on what controller? whats dd?

Comment: Instead of `var_dump($car);`, try `dd($card)` and let me know what you get. dd - die and dump

Comment: i dont get any, even my var_dump doesnt get any since my page just refresh when i click submit, i think it does not go to update function, i do think there is a problem in my routes though

Comment: @Viscocent Where's the form's `action` attribute?

Comment: @DoanTran i left it blank to use default, it sends it to the same page

Comment: @Viscocent Use `action` attribute in your `form` starting tag. Ex: `action="{{ action('CarsController@update',[$car->id]) }}"`

Comment: @smartrahat - MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: @Viscocent use `method="patch"` in form starting tag. And in route.php `Route::patch('cars/{id}/edit','CarsController@update');` or `Route::patch('cars/edit/{id}/edit','CarsController@update');`

Comment: I think the issue here is that it finds a match for the route, but it's on the wrong request type. Just give the form an action and change the route address.

Answer (score 0):

The `$id` variable in whereIn must be array and you need to specify the database column too. This should be like -

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $car = Cars::whereId('id', [$id])->firstOrFail();
    return view('cars.edit', compact('car'));
}
```

Change all occurrence of

```
$car = car::whereId($id)->firstOrFail();
```